# I'm trying to get timezone name using GMT value

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have unix timestamps created in a database table. I know user's timezone it is also saved in a table and int the format of "GMT+04:00" , "GMT+05:30"

What I'm trying to do is take the timestamp and show readable time to the users according to their timezone.

Ex.

```
$startTime = '1524391500';

echo date('h:ia', $startTime) . '<br>';
date_default_timezone_set('America/Fortaleza');
echo date('h:ia', $startTime) . '<br>';
```

this will give us the result

```
10:05am
07:05am
```

The problem is date_default_timezone_set doesn't accept the timezone in this

```
date_default_timezone_set('GMT+05:30');
```

So I need a way to convert "GMT+05:30" to something like "America/Fortaleza"

can some one help me with this?

Comment: It would be better for you to save the user's timezone in the `America/Fortaleza`-like format, if you need to display it back as a name. Just so you know - **there is not always 1:1 relationship between timezone name and its offset**. For example your `America/Fortaleza` has the same offset *(`UTC−03:00`)* as `America/Cordoba` or `Antarctica/Rothera` (and many more).

Comment: @Smuuf yes, the database already created and data saved by some other developer. I have to use it. I think if we can get at least one matching timezone it will be enough because I don't need the exact time zone, only need to show the correct time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible.  A time zone and a time zone offset are two different things.

Consider a single time zone like `America/Sao_Paulo`.  It uses an offset of `-03:00` during Standard Time, and an offset of `-02:00` during Daylight Saving Time.

Now consider that `America/Fortaleza` you mentioned uses `-03:00` over the entire year.

As you can see, for a given time zone I may have more than one offset, and for a given offset I may have more than one time zone.  You can [review the lists of time zones and their offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) if you want to find more examples for yourself.

This is covered extensively in other answers, as well as in the "Time Zone != Offset" section of [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.